# How to disable auto-entitying by DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm parsing a HTML string with DOMDocument. I'm loading it this way:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8"><div id="container">'.$text.'</div>', LIBXML_NOENT);
```

Then, I'm running some XPath queries and node replacing on it. (Even if I comment out these actions, the characters are still getting replaced.) Finally, I'm saving it this way:

```
$parsed = $dom->saveHTML();
```

But DOMDocument seems to be replacing non-ASCII characters with its entity representation. For example, string in Czech language:

```
ěščřžýáíé
```

Returns:

```
&#283;&scaron;&#269;&#345;&#382;&yacute;&aacute;&iacute;&eacute;
```

I can't use `html_entity_decode()`, because it breaks already highlighted and properly escaped source code.

What should I do to disable automatic replacing non-ASCII characters with entities by DOMDocument (so, the above example will return also `ěščřžýáíé`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have a solution. It is so simple, just instead of `<?xml encoding="UTF-8">` use `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`.

Comment: I've done some digging and found out that it depends on PHP version, respectively on libxml version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$text = <div id="container">'.$text.'</div>';
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
$dom->encoding='UTF-8';
$dom->loadHTML($text);
```

ok, do you try to change method:

```
$dom->loadXML();
```

by defaul it uses utf-8, but $text must be xhtml formated
if $text is not formated try:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<meta charset="utf-8"/>'.$text);
```

If you read data from browser, try this:

```
  echo '<meta charset="utf-8" />';
  echo  $parsed;
```

Comment: Not working, the characters are still being converted (PHP 5.4.19, DOM/XML API 20031129, libxml 2.7.8).

Comment: String is not XHTML formatted and the second method produces bad results (also entities, but this time they're not equal to original character).

Comment: I'm not that stupid. I'm dealing with this problem for approximately one week, so, I really need help.

Comment: sorry. maybe something wrong with php settings. Do you try setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'cs_CZ.UTF-8'); ?

Comment: $text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);

Comment: And this try: ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none");
  $text= mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'); I hope you find solution.